# Call body class not working in MSIE

Tags: php, wordpress, class, browser

Working on a shortcode based on browser body classes. The way I have it set up is working in every browser except MSIE. This is not the complete conditional statement, but I've isolated the problem down to this. MSIE can't get past this:

```
$classes = get_body_class();
if (in_array('msie',$classes)){
    echo 'MSIE';
}
```

If you change msie to firefox, or any other of my browser classes, it works. But with MSIE, it's not returning or echoing anything.

It's happening with IE10 to be specific. Haven't tested lower yet. A `vardump` of `$classes` produced, among others, this: `string(9) "msie ie10"`

Comment: What does `get_body_classes()` contain?

Comment: You're looking to see if `msie` is in the output from `get_body_class()`. What does `get_body_class()` return? (Ooops. I've just spotted the typo in my original comment - sorry!)

Comment: Well, forgive my noobiness, when I view source in IE, msie is one of the body classes. I put it there. But I don't know how to return get_body_class.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the wordpress function http://wpseek.com/get_body_class/ this function does not add the browser type to classes applied to the body tag.

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($classes)` to your code? That will print out the exact contents of the variable `$classes`, so you can see what's in there.

Comment: I've already added them in another function. The body class is there.

Comment: Will try that andrewsi.

Comment: Among all the others, this came out in the vardump: string(9) "msie ie10"

Comment: @Thom for future reference you should add the vardump results to the original question using edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array()` doesn't do partial matching. So if the value is `msie ie10` the code you have won't find it you would need to do this:

```
$classes = get_body_class();
if (in_array('msie ie10',$classes)){
    echo 'MSIE';
}
```

Another option if you want to do partial matching is using a foreach loop.

```
$classes = get_body_class();
foreach($classes as $class) {
    if(strpos($class,'msie') !== false) {
        echo 'MSIE';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like my answer. So I would just do one of those conditionals for each version of ie as well.